# Alternative way of creating docx files in android

Tags: java, php, android, web-services, apache-poi

So I did some searching about POI (Used to make word documents using java) and did some implementation of it. It works well when running it in java. When running the java in android I get an error so that app crashes. There is no support for creating docx file, other than using 3rd party apps.

My idea so far is to use a web service. Sending the information through a php post request. The php script will execute a jar file to make the docx file. The information will be used as arguments for a jar program. After it is created it is emailed to an email address (specified in the app) from noreply@myapp.com

I don't know yet how the php script will run the jar file. I'm still very noob at php.

Is the approach worth doing? Any alternative ways?

Comment: "The php script will execute a jar file to make the docx file." Why on earth would you wrap your Java code in PHP?

Comment: @Chris I'm not wrapping the java code itself in php. I going to use something like shell_exec('/tmp/runTheJar.sh') in the php to run the jar file. And the only way that I can access the web host machine is through php.

Comment: Why not use one of the patched versions of Apache POI aimed at Android developers, eg https://github.com/centic9/poi-on-android ?

Comment: @Gagravarr Thank you. This is a much better way of doing it

Comment: @Gagravarr But it lacks to do docx files. It only does xlsx spread sheets.